# hiding bootstrap forms and use pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this maybe easy for you all guys but i didn't understand why my form for adding user outputs at the bottom even if i add pagination to my ul class it will add design to the dropdown but still there is a form i try hiding it with jquery but if i show and hide elements it will take lots of .show and .hide want it to be summarized and also hide the form

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta name="description" content="SHIELD - Free Bootstrap 3 Theme">
                <meta name="author" content="Carlos Alvarez - Alvarez.is - blacktie.co">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">


                <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

                <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
                <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icomoon.css">
                <link href="assets/css/animate-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">



                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

                <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                  <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
                  <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
              </head>

              <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navbar-main">


                <div id="navbar-main">
                  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon icon-shield" style="font-size:30px; color:#3498db;"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="#home"><span class="icon icon-shield" style="font-size:18px; color:#3498db;"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style = "font-weight:strong; font-family:Verdana;">
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"> About</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#services" class="smoothScroll"> Services</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#team" class="smoothScroll"> Team</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll"> Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#blog" class="smoothScroll"> Blog</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"> Contact</a></li></ul>
                        <div style = "position:relative; left:550px;">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style = "font-weight:strong; font-family:Verdana; margin-right:0px;">
                                <li> <a href="index.html" class="smoothScroll"> Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>




                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>      
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Users<span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#" data-target = "#home" data-toggle="collapse">Add</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Employee Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">All Users</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Audit Trail</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>          
                    <li ><a href="#">Announcements<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span></a></li>        
                    <li ><a href="#">Orders<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#">Stocks<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <form id = "home">
              <!-- ==== PORTFOLIO ==== -->
                    <div class="container" id="portfolio" name="portfolio">
                    <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <br>
                            <h1 class="centered">Admin</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                        <div class="container">

                        <div class="row">   

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
            <form id = "adduser">
              <!-- ==== PORTFOLIO ==== -->
                    <div class="container" id="portfolio" name="portfolio">
                    <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <br>
                            <h1 class="centered">Add User</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                        <div class="container">

                        <div class="row">   

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>         

            <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
                ================================================== -->
                <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->


                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/retina.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-func.js"></script>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#adduser").hide();
                });
                </script>
              </body>
            </html>
```

if i click home the admin form will be displayed if i click the add adding form will be displayed and the admin form will be hidden

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for your question. Can you edit it and add all html and please edit your question and make it more clear https://jsfiddle.net/moneer99/acxnzpfj/

Comment: could you please help me .. is it more understandable now? sorry new in bootstrap

Comment: please update this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/moneer99/acxnzpfj/2/ I can't see any toggle buttons

Comment: i updated it https://jsfiddle.net/acxnzpfj/4/

Comment: if u click mange users and then the add tab the big admin word will be hidden and then the Add user word will be left

Comment: And what do you want? keeping the admin word?

Comment: changing display outputs without leaving the web page

Comment: `without leaving the web page`, this doesn't happen. When clicking add, it does not leave the web page already. What leaving your talking about?

Comment: i googled it bootstrap dynamic pagination thats what all i meant but instead of pagination .. i want it for my drop down

Comment: Ok, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to implement is a dynamic page navigation (not pagination)

**General idea:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moneer99/x2h3tbgv/)

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav">
  <li><a href="#add" data-toggle="tab">Add</a></li>
  <li><a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab">Edit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#report" data-toggle="tab">report</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="add">This is add</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="edit">This is edit</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="report">This is report</div>
</div>
```

and I applied this to your example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/moneer99/4ec6fqyr/). Hopefully this helps